# How can I prevent simultaneous changes to a list from timer and socket events?

Tags: delphi, sockets, timer

I am developing an application in which I must handle some lists (insertion, deletion). The problem is that the list can suffer alteration from a TTimer component and from a TServerSocket.

How can I protect the lists from being altered by the TTimer and the TServerSocket at the same time? Should I use threads?

Comment: Take a look at TThreadList in the delphi help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timer events are running in the application's main thread. I am not sure about TServerSocket events (may be a configuration option).

Generally: If both accesses are running in the main thread, you do not need a critical section because the other event can only fire when the first event has already finished (unless you call Application.ProcessMessages which you shouldn't anyway). A critical section wouldn't work in this scenario any way because it will only sync separate threads.

If they are running in different threads, you need some kind of synchronization. A critical section is one option, others include Mutexes, spin locks etc.

Comment: If the `TServerSocket` is created in the main thread and is running in non-blocking mode, its events are triggered by the main thread message queue - the same thing that is triggering the `TTimer` events.  So all of the events are serialized automatically for you.  On the other hand, if the `TServerSocket` is running in blocking mode instead, then its events (if events are even used - they are optional in that mode) are triggered in worker threads instead, in which case you then have to provide your own inter-thread lock around the list accesses.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this or a variation thereof:
http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=2167

Comment: Answers that are just posting a link are likely to be deleted by a moderator because the answer will become useless if/when the link "rots" (becomes invalid). If you want your answer to survive and perhaps even get some votes, you really should provide at least a summary of what can be found there.

Comment: Never though of that, it's true of course. The link points to the TThreadStringList component written by Tilo Eckert.